# Is there a way to stop iOS today extension sending API requests in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, today-extension

I'm trying to stop sending API requests in background, when the today extension is not visible. API requests are pretty expensive, so I would like to optimize the number of sent requests. Where should I put API request so it will be called only when the today extension become visible and will not be called in background?

I have already tried to set `NCUpdateResultNoData` however `viewDidLoad` is called in background in that case. In `viewDidLoad` I send API request to update the today extension when it becomes visible.

```
- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNoData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a tricky question, what you can try is to fire your request in `viewWillAppear:` but this means that your UI will probably not be ready in `viewDidAppear:` but you can handle this using an activity indicator.

From the docs:

> // If the widget has local state that can be loaded quickly, it should
>   do so before returning from ‘viewWillAppear:’. // Otherwise, the
>   widget should ensure that the state and layout of its view when
>   returning from 'viewWillAppear:’ will match that of the last time it
>   returned from 'viewWillDisappear:', transitioning smoothly to the new
>   data later when it arrives.”

Comment: Unfortunately, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are also called when the system is making snapshots in background.